# I want a different color only for first row of a html table

Tags: css, html-table, background-color

I used a table. I applied CSS ID `table-4`.

Following the html code:

```
<table border='0' width='100%' id='table-4'>
   <tr><td>Date</td><td>Headline</td></tr>
   <tr><td>29 DEC</td><td>Dead</td></tr>
   <tr><td>30 DEC</td><td>Hit</td></tr>
   <tr><td>02 JAN</td><td>Leg</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the style.css:

```
#table-4 { background-color: #F2F2F2;}
```

So the whole table's background color is `#F2F2F2`, but I want a different color for the first row where `Date` and `Headline` goes, so how could I modify my CSS for this thing?

Comment: use thead for your head, if cannot use table `tr:first-child td` selector

Comment: I can't get you, Jonathan.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Comment: Using a `THEAD` tag is the most semantically correct way to go. Using the `:first-child` CSS selector is also a good solution, especially if you can't modify the HTML. I would recommend adding the `THEAD` tag and styling that if possible. It's specifically created to mark your column headers (basically, when reading your HTML, your first `TR` wrapped in a `THEAD` tag means "This column is the 'Date' column", "This column is the 'Headline' column", etc.).

Comment: @thirdender: "your first TR wrapped in a THEAD tag means "This column is the 'Date' column", "This column is the 'Headline", etc." - that's not quite right. the `<thead>` tag says "this section of the table is the heading section." It doesn't say that every cell in it is a column header. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-thead-element.html#the-thead-element) You need `<th>` cells with a `scope` attribute for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **:first-child** for this. Write like this:

```
#table-4 tr:first-child{
    background:red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cbK8J/

Comment: it's working, thanks. could you tell me how I can change text color of 1st row too?

Comment: simple add your style properties inside the brackets. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cbK8J/1/

Answer (score 4):

[@JonathandeM.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154342/i-want-a-different-color-only-for-1st-row-of-a-html-table/#comment19605185_14154342) is correct. Pop `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags in there, and change the `<td>` tags in the `<thead>` row to `<th>` tags (because HTML says what things are, and they're headings):

```
<table border='0' width='100%' id='table-4'>
   <thead>
      <tr><th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Headline</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>29 DEC</td><td>Dead</td></tr>
      <tr><td>30 DEC</td><td>Hit</td></tr>
      <tr><td>02 JAN</td><td>Leg</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the CSS to make the heading row have a different background colour is:

```
#table-4 thead tr {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

HTML:

```
<td class="whatever">Date</td><td class="whatever">Headline</td>
```

css:

```
.whatever { color: #a9a9a9 }
```

`<tr>` will do the row, `<td>` will do the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add id to first tr tag:

```
   <table border='0' width='100%' id='table-4'>
   <tr id ="r1" ><td>Date</td><td>Headline</td></tr>
   <tr><td>29 DEC</td><td>Dead</td></tr>
   <tr><td>30 DEC</td><td>Hit</td></tr>
   <tr><td>02 JAN</td><td>Leg</td></tr>
   </table>
```

and then add another css line:

```
#table-4 #r1 { background-color: blue;}
```

it will give you blue color

Comment: Or you could use the `:first-child` selector.

Comment: ok, you can '#table-4 tr:first-child { background-color: blue;}'

Comment: it's working, thanks. could you tell me how I can change text color of 1st row too?

Comment: just add `color: white;` ie: `#table-4 tr:first-child { background-color: blue; color: white}`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply modify only the Html file, no change in css

```
    <table border='0' width='100%' id='table-4'>
    <tr><td bgcolor='red' >Date</td><td  bgcolor='red'>Headline</td></tr>
    <tr><td>29 DEC</td><td>Dead</td></tr>
    <tr><td>30 DEC</td><td>Hit</td></tr>
   <tr><td>02 JAN</td><td>Leg</td></tr>
   </table>
```